# Can't find SSIS project in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: sql, visual-studio-2015, ssis, sql-server-2017

I've recently installed SQL Server 2017 developer and Visual studio 2015. However, I can't seem to find the SSIS project in visual studio 2015. Any ideas?

Comment: What have you done to look for it?   How can we know if you're looking in the wrong place, or if there's something else wrong?   How do we know you even have a project to be found?

Answer (score 3):

I think you'll need download and install SSDT (SQL Server Data Tools).
It's an official addon for Visual Studio which adds templates for SSIS and SSAS projects.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/download-sql-server-data-tools-ssdt

Comment: Thanks. I initially installed SSDT initially that was part of the VS2015 installation but that didn't work so ended up SSDT as a seperate package from the Microsoft site and that worked.